# XML Parsing and sorting

Tags: java, android, xml

I have the following XML file with stations where I need to find the shortest distance to them.

```
<station>
<station_id>TAPA</station_id>
<latitude>17.117</latitude>
<longitude>-61.783</longitude>
<xml_url>http://weather.gov/xml/current_obs/TAPA.xml</xml_url>
</station>

<station>
<station_id>TKPN</station_id>
<latitude>17.2</latitude>
<longitude>-62.583</longitude>
<xml_url>http://weather.gov/xml/current_obs/TKPN.xml</xml_url>
</station>

<station>
<station_name>Blackburne/Plymouth</station_name>
<latitude>16.75</latitude>
<longitude>-62.167</longitude>
<xml_url>http://weather.gov/xml/current_obs/TRPM.xml</xml_url>
</station>
```

After parsing I'm storing this data in Station object which implements Comparable to sort the distance(i can calculate it using longitude and latitude).

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void...params){
    ....

    Station station = null;

    double stationLatitude = 0;
    double stationLongitude = 0;
    String xml = null;
    double distance = 0;

    ArrayList<Station> data = new ArrayList<Station>();

    for (int i = 0; i < itemList.getLength();i++){
        currentItem = itemList.item(i);
        //Log.i("Current Item: ", "" + currentItem.getNodeName());
        itemChildren = currentItem.getChildNodes();

        //..creating object Station
        station = new Station();
        for (int j = 0; j < itemChildren.getLength(); j++){

            currentChild = itemChildren.item(j);

            if (currentChild.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("latitude")){

                stationLatitude = Double.parseDouble(currentChild.getTextContent());

                //Log.i("Latitude: ", "" + stationLatitude);

                station.setLatitude(stationLatitude);

            } else if (currentChild.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("longitude")){

                stationLongitude = Double.parseDouble(currentChild.getTextContent());

                //Log.i("Longitude: ", "" + stationLongitude);

                station.setLongitude(stationLongitude);

            } else if (currentChild.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("xml_url")){

                xml = currentChild.getTextContent();

                // Log.i("XML: ", "" + xml);

                station.setUrl(xml);
            }

            //inadeqaute values after quitting if/else:
            Log.i("Latitude: ", "" + station.getLatitude());
            Log.i("Longitude: ", "" + station.getLongitude());

            distance = calcDistance(deviceLongitude, deviceLatitude, station.getLongitude(), station.getLatitude());

            station.setDistance(distance);

            data.add(station);

        }

    }
    Collections.sort(data);

    Log.i("Shortest distance", "" + data.get(0).getDistance());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
}
```

So the problem is I'm getting inadequate latitude and longitude values(too many of them, which are being stored in object):

```
02-21 13:30:10.762 29803-29843/com.andro.location I/Latitude:: 0.0
02-21 13:30:10.762 29803-29843/com.andro.location I/Longitude:: 0.0
02-21 13:30:10.762 29803-29843/com.andro.location I/Latitude:: 0.0
02-21 13:30:10.762 29803-29843/com.andro.location I/Longitude:: 0.0
02-21 13:30:10.762 29803-29843/com.andro.location I/Latitude:: 17.117
02-21 13:30:10.772 29803-29843/com.andro.location I/Longitude:: 0.0
02-21 13:30:10.772 29803-29843/com.andro.location I/Latitude:: 17.117
02-21 13:30:10.772 29803-29843/com.andro.location I/Longitude:: 0.0
02-21 13:30:10.772 29803-29843/com.andro.location I/Latitude:: 17.117
02-21 13:30:10.772 29803-29843/com.andro.location I/Longitude:: -61.783
02-21 13:30:10.772 29803-29843/com.andro.location I/Latitude:: 17.117
02-21 13:30:10.772 29803-29843/com.andro.location I/Latitude:: 17.117
02-21 13:30:10.772 29803-29843/com.andro.location I/Longitude:: -61.783
02-21 13:30:10.772 29803-29843/com.andro.location I/Latitude:: 17.117
02-21 13:30:10.782 29803-29843/com.andro.location I/Latitude:: 0.0
02-21 13:30:10.782 29803-29843/com.andro.location I/Longitude:: 0.0
02-21 13:30:10.782 29803-29843/com.andro.location I/Latitude:: 0.0
02-21 13:30:10.782 29803-29843/com.andro.location I/Longitude:: 0.0
02-21 13:30:10.782 29803-29843/com.andro.location I/Latitude:: 0.0
02-21 13:30:10.782 29803-29843/com.andro.location I/Longitude:: 0.0
```

When it comes to sorting: `Collections.sort(data);` I'm getting "Comparison method violates its general contract" Exception:/

Edit: adding Station class:

```
public class Station implements Comparable<Station> {

    public double getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public void setDistance(double distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    double distance;
    String url;
    double longitude;
    double latitude;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Station other) {

        int result = this.distance <= other.distance ? -1 : 1;
        return result;
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you show how you implemented Comparable interface in Station class?

Comment: show us your Station entire class

Comment: Edited my post, thanks

Comment: That's what I'm getting after logging Station object: http://i.imgsafe.org/4d6d38d.jpg

Comment: You should move the last 3 lines of the inner `for` loop outside so you won't insert the *same* station object 4 times into the list.

Comment: Just figured this out, Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

change the compareTo method to

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Station other) {

    return Double.compare(this.distance, other.distance)
}
```

credit to [@Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221149/andreas) for the cleaner answer

Comment: Didn't help. It's must be something with creating object within if/else block, must be bad idea. But I didn't figure that yet

Comment: Shorter version: [`return Double.compare(this.distance, other.distance)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare%28double,%20double%29).

Comment: basically the problem is when by chance you have two equal values that you send to your current comparator... it would say whichever one calls the comparator is smaller... i.e. if `a.compareTo(b)` =>-1 and `b.compareTo(a)` =>-1  then b>a and a>b which is impossible...